# Proving $\arctan(|x-y|)\leqslant\arctan(|x|)+\arctan(|y|)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have a challenging question today. It looks easy but I have no idea how to prove it, so I need your help. The question is:

> Prove that$$\arctan(|x-y|)\leqslant\arctan(|x|)+\arctan(|y|).$$

We have:
$$y \geq 0 \implies \arctan(x-y) ≤ \arctan(x)+\arctan(y) \tag{1}$$
$$y \leq 0\implies \arctan(x-y) ≥ \arctan(x)+\arctan(y) \tag{2}$$
$$|\arctan(x)| = \arctan(|x|) \tag{3}$$
It is easy to prove those three formulas.

Comment: What are you asking for? To check your proof (it seems wrong) or to give a correct proof?

Comment: use LMVT it will be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$\text{Let }\, f(a)=\arctan (a+b) -\arctan (a) \;  \text{and} \; a,b >0.  \tag{i} $$

$$\text{Then }\, f'(a)=\frac 1 {1+(a+b)^{2}} -\frac 1 {1+a^{2}} <0. \tag{ii}$$

Hence $f$ is a decreasing function with

$$f(0)=\arctan (b),\tag{iii}$$

$$f(a) \leq \arctan \,b \quad \quad a,b \in \Bbb{R}.\tag{iv}$$

Thus 
$$\arctan (a+b) \leq \arctan (a) +\arctan (b).\tag{v}$$

Now use the fact that $\arctan $ is an increasing function to see that

$$\arctan |x-y| \leq \arctan (|x|+|y|) \leq \arctan |x| +\arctan |y|\tag{vi}.$$

Comment: I don't see anthing wrong with the last part.

Comment: $arctan$ is increasing because its derivative $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$ is positive. Since $|x-y| \leq |x|+|y|$ we get $arctan (|x-y|) \leq arctan (|x| +|y)|$. Now apply (v).